# Get Object of a array by refering one key in particular obect

Tags: arrays, json, powershell

Trying to get all the elements out of an object by knowing one element

```
var:[
{
 name:"ben",
 age:"24"
},
name:"chris",
age:"35"
}
]
```

want to get age by name inside of the particular object

```
name:"ben",
age:"24"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working with a properly formatted JSON file, you can do the following:

```
$json = @'
{
"var": [
{
 "name":"ben",
 "age":"24"
},
{
"name":"chris",
"age":"35"
}
]
}
'@ | ConvertFrom-Json 

$json.var.where{$_.name -eq "ben"} | ConvertTo-Json
```

You could do the following if you want the object list formatted output rather than the JSON format.

```
$json.var.where{$_.name -eq "ben"} | Format-List
```

**Explanation:**

You can pipe your formatted JSON data into `ConvertFrom-Json` to create a `PSCustomObject`. Then you can conditionally query against the property values. `Where()` method is a good option here. Finally, you can pipe back out to `ConvertTo-Json` to return the output in the original JSON format. Keep in mind that the output will include the surrounding `{}`.